# Check if no Outlook email, with today's date as received date, in folder using Access VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I check a specific folder to see if an email exists with today's date as the received date.

The code below loops through the emails and sends me an email message if an email exists with today's date as the received date.

I want it to also send me an email if there are zero results.

The closest I got was to get six results all indicating the mail item does not exist (since there were 6 messages with dates not equal to today).

```
For Each olMail In OlItems

        'Cond #1  Received today?
        If (Now() - olMail.ReceivedTime < 1) Then
            '...Cond #2 ...and has specific string
             If (InStr(1, olMail.Body, "L_Remittance_YYYYMMDD", 1) > 0) Then
                   '......'Cond #3  and Has attachment?
             If olMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                         '..Cond 4 ...and has data in results  [ "0" evaluates to string not existing  ]  ?
             If (InStr(1, olMail.Body, "No Data Available", 1) = 0) Then


                      'Cond 1-4 all true then save to drop location
                      For j = 1 To olMail.Attachments.Count
                      olMail.Attachments.Item(j).SaveAsFile strFolder & 
                        olMail.Attachments.Item(j).FileName


            ''Loop through files in folder ie For Each o1Mail in OlItems
            Next j

                        'Cond 4
                       End If
                'Cond 3
                 End If
           'Cond 2
           End If
    ''Cond #1
    End If


    Next
    '' If (Now() - olMail.ReceivedTime < 1) = "" Then
    '' Call FailFile
    '' Else
    ''Exit Sub
    ''End If

    Set OlFolder = Nothing
    Set OlItems = Nothing
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set OlApp = Nothing

     ''NO DATA IN FILE AS PER EMAIL BODY

    aFile = "H:\TEST_DROP\FileName_" & CurrentDate & ".csv"
    If Len(Dir$(aFile)) = 0 Then

       Call NoData

    End If


                ''YES TO DATA IN FILE

    aFile = "H:\TEST_DROP\Metlife_Remittance_Berkadia_" & CurrentDate & ".csv"
    If Len(Dir$(aFile)) > 0 Then
            Call Data
    End If


    End Sub
```

Comment: So just to be clear, I want to query an outlook folder for a mail message with today's date and when it does not exist, do something.  It really is that simple (well...not for me anyway.)  thanks.

Comment: Just create a boolean variable that turns to TRUE right when you step into `If (Now() - olMail.RecievedTime < 1)`. Once your loop is complete check the status of the boolean variable. If it is false, then no email was found

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to create and check the status of the variable....kind of novice here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your first condition tracks the criteria you are looking for.

1. Create Boolean variable `rec_today`
2. Set `rec_today` = `FALSE`
3. Loop through all emails
4. Switch `rec_today` to `TRUE` **ONLY IF** your first condition is met
5. Check condition of `rec_today` at the end of the loop.

Notice that if your first criteria is never met (email received today), `rec_today` will never be swapped to `TRUE`. Therefore, your actions should be based around the outcome of this variable.

---

```
Dim rec_today As Boolean            
rec_today = False                 '<---START AT FALSE

For Each olMail In OlItems
    If (Now() - olMail.ReceivedTime < 1) Then            '<--- FLIP TO TRUE HERE
      rec_today = True
        If (InStr(1, olMail.Body, "L_Remittance_YYYYMMDD", 1) > 0) Then
             If olMail.Attachments.Count > 0 Then
                If (InStr(1, olMail.Body, "No Data Available", 1) = 0) Then
                    For j = 1 To olMail.Attachments.Count
                        olMail.Attachments.Item(j).SaveAsFile strFolder & olMail.Attachments.Item(j).Filename
                    Next j
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next


If rec_today = TRUE Then
    'Code here that should run if email was found from today
Else      
    'Code here that should run if NO EMAIL was found from today
    'i.e. rec_today = FALSE
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem with the above is, that since it currently is looping through other emails in that folder that are <> today, it returns the first false it hits instead of looping through all the mails and finding a true.....so it returns a false false....   so to restate another way, since there are other emails in that folder that were not received today, and since the if statement loops through them first before finding the current date email, it returns a false based on the other emails and skips right over the current date received email....

Comment: This doesn’t go back and forth. It starts as FALSE and will only flip to TRUE once. The first time a email is found, then you no longer have reason to take any action of the case an email is not found, correct?

Comment: Since the first email it looks it predates today it evaluates it as false and immediately  ends the IF condition and executes the :
End If

If rec_today = False Then

   MsgBox "No emails were found today"
    'execute code for this instance here
    Exit Sub
End If

Next

Comment: Agh. Well I don’t follow what you need then. But I think the strategy you want is similar to what I have here. You may just need to reposition the Boolean statement somewhere that suits your criteria.

Comment: I see.  Let me put this boolean check portion in the beginning before anything since it is basically a dead stop if there are no emails received today.

Comment: Thank you for giving me good direction!!!  It should work with this.  Using boolean variable are powerful tools I see!

Comment: How do I "accept" solution?  Don't see where to click....to accept....Oh, nevermind, I see ...just click the check button at left...on it..